# ImageMagick not setting color space

Tags: colors, imagemagick

I'm writing a Python script to batch-process several thousand images. All images are in sRGB, and I'm trying to make a single collage of them. For this I thought I'd first have ImageMagick create an empty file (in which to insert all images afterwards), like so:

`convert -size 4000x6000 -density 350 -canvas:white collageFile.psd`

This indeed creates a PSD file with the desired dimensions and DPI, but the color space is 'Gray' ('Dot gain 20%' to be precise). I did various searches and found a number of options:

- `-type TrueColor` to force a color document
- `-set colorspace sRGB` to specify a colorspace in case the file has none
- `-colorspace RGB` to convert to a colorspace (?)
- `-profile /ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB.icm` to assign a color profile located on my computer

Unfortunately, none of these work, nor do any combination of them. Does anyone know what I'm missing here? I'm using `ImageMagick 6.9.7-0 Q16 x86_64`

Comment: What happens if you replace `-canvas:white` with `-threshold -1 -alpha off`?

Comment: `convert: no images defined '/path/to/collageFile.psd' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.`